# How to retrieve data from Future object properly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using shared preferences. I want to get the list of strings, but for some reason it's always a null though it shouldn't be. I think I'm making a mistake in asynchronous stuff. Can somebody help me? With explanation if possible.

```
List<String> getSaved() {
  List<String>? items;
  Future<SharedPreferences> prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.then((prefs) async {
    items = prefs.getStringList('saved');
  });
  // SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // items = prefs.getStringList('saved');
  return items ?? [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the result when the future completed your function should be of type `Future<List<String>>` and you can use then or await knowing that items should be of the same type too

```
 Future<List<String>> getSaved() async {
       List<String>? items;
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         items = prefs.getStringList('saved');
       // SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       // items = prefs.getStringList('saved');
       return items ?? [];
     }
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I used this in a widget constructor `() async => _saved = await getSaved();` and _saved is [ ] (empty list). What am I missing?

Comment: Use a FutureBuilder, it's a widget that waits a future function